# how to resolve "throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK()"?

Tags: iota-network, testnet

i'm facing following error while running command **mvn clean compile** :

```
fs.js:137
    throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK();
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function
    at makeCallback (fs.js:137:11)
    at Object.mkdir (fs.js:713:16)
    at Object.target.init (C:\Users\Percept\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mvn\target.js:25:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Percept\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mvn\target.js:39:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
```

Comment: Could you add some more information? What software did you try to compile?

Comment: i'm using terminal in visual studio code!! @Tobi MZ

Comment: what code did you want to compile? iota js lib? Did you check your node.js version?